# Finding the order of elements in a group?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

For $x \in X$, let $[x] = \{y \in X | f(y) = f(x)\}$ and let $U_n = \{[a] \in \mathbb{Z}_n | \gcd(a, n) = 1\}$ (the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}_n$). Determine the order of $[4] \in U_{23}$.

What exactly is this question asking? (What does it mean to find the order of $[4]$?) Am I to find $|U_n|$? Am I to find $\phi(n)$ (Euler phi function)? I am trying to go over my notes and find some relevant example, but no luck. A clarification of this problem would be very useful.

Edit: additional information originally left out

For any sets $X,Y$ and any function $f:X→Y$, there exists an equivalence relation defined on $X$ called $Ker(f)=\{(x1,x2)|f(x1)=f(x2)\}$. Also, $X/Ker(f)=\{[x]|x∈X\}$ where for $x∈X, [x]=\{y∈X|f(y)=f(x)\}$.

Comment: What in the world of ill-posed questions is $\,f\,$?!

Comment: The order of an element $a$ is $$ord(a) =\min \{ n \in \mathbb{N} \ : \ a^n=1\}$$

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to define as much as I can while still keeping things terse. "For any sets $X, Y$ and any function $f: X \to Y$, there exists an equivalence relation defined on $X$, $Ker(f)$. Also, $X / Ker(f) = \{[x] | x \in X\}$ where for $x \in X$, $[x] = \{y \in X | f(y) = f(x)\}$".

Comment: And what exactly is $\,\ker f\,$ when we talk of a function between *sets*?...

Comment: $Ker(f) = \{(x_1, x_2) | f(x_1) = f(x_2)\}$.

Comment: Then perhaps you should edit your question adding all this very relevant information.

Comment: Finally: what does the very first part of your question have to do with *the actual* question? How maps between set, their kernels and equivalence is related to $\,U_n\,$ and stuff?

Comment: The first part of my question IS the question I am asking. I simply do not know how to begin, and I am trying to seek help as well as provide background info on what we have learned prior to this.

Comment: @DonAntonio My guess is that they defined $\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z$ as the Kernel of the mapping $a$ to remainder $a:n$.... But then that is irrelevant to the question...

Comment: @user41419 Any chance you can post the exact question as is stated? Without adding any extra "helpfull" information or background...... To help you, is the question asking ONLY "Determine the order of $[4] \in U_{23}$"?

Comment: Yes, that is the exact question. Sorry for any confusion, I thought I might have had to clarify some of my notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem asks you to find the first positive integer $n$ such that

$$[4]^n=[1]$$

If you learned about $\phi(23)$ this makes the problem simpler: this $n$ must divide $\phi(23)=22$. Thus there are only four choices for $n$: 1, 2, 11, 22.

$n=1$ clearly doesn't work, you now have to decide for $n=2$ and $n=11$. You already know that 22 works, but have to figure which is the first one to work...

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification! I think I understand this problem now.

Comment: Alright, so I picked up where you left off, and I found the following. $[4]^2 = [16]$, so $n = 2$ does not work. However, $[4]^{11} = [1]$, so $n = 11$ and since $11$ is least, then the order of $[4]$ is 11. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. Note that the reason why you know that one of the 4 works is because by Euler Theorem (or Fermat Little Theorem) $[4]^{22}=[1]$, and one of the properties of the order sais that whenever $[a]^n=[1]$ the order must divide $n$....